# C++ If Statement Run-Time Check Failure #2

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, cin

I have a code here:(ignore the `friends_name`, that's fine)

```
char friend_sex [1];

cout << "Please enter m if your friend is male or f if your friend is female\n";

cin >> friend_sex; 
    if (friend_sex == "m") cout << "If you see " << friends_name << "! please ask him to call me\n";

    if (friend_sex == "f") cout << "If you see " << friends_name << "! please ask her to call me\n";
```

When I run it it says

> Run-Time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'friend_sex' was corrupted.

Comment: I bet because you have an array of one the stream operators are making it a string, rather than a char.

Comment: Since `friend_sex` decays to a pointer to a variable of type `char` and `"m"` is a pointer to a constant of type `char`, it's almost inconceivable that these two pointers could ever be equivalent in value. How could both a constant and a variable be at the same address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Change `char friend_sex[1]` to `char friend_sex`, and `"m"` to `'m'`, `"f"` to `'f'`.
2. Change `char friend_sex[1]` to `char friend_sex[2]`. And change the `==` judgement to `strcmp`.

Comment: In `c++`, it's more appropriate to use `std::string::compare`.

Comment: As a c++ programmer #2 should be discouraged.

Comment: Agree with you all.

Comment: Thanks :D been stuck on this for 2 hours.... 2 HOURS AAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Comment: I hope you used the #1 solution.

Comment: Now stuck on this :(

cout << "How old is your friend?\n";

 int age;

 cin >> age;

 cout << "I hear your had a birthday and your " << age << " years old\n";

 if (age <= '0') cout << "error(you're kidding!)\n";

 if (age > '110') cout << "error(you're kidding!)\n";

 cin.get();

 cin.get();

Comment: `if (age <= '0')` is wrong. With that said StackOverflow is 1 question per question. `if (age > '110')` is also wrong. You need to understand when to use quotes and what quote to use. In this case with integers you don't want any quotes at all. Also '110' does not make sense. ' is for quoting a single character.

Answer (score 1):

I think i'm correct if i'm saying that you use Visual Studio ( due to the error message ).

What happened is known as "buffer overflow", which consist in writing where you after the buffer location in the memory

To avoid that, you can change the data type of `friend_sex` to an `std::string`, which will solve your problems